# Azure Front Door and iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, azure, safari, azure-front-door

I set up an Azure Front Door (proxy/caching/load balancing) in front of my web app [www.JewPaltz.com](http://www.JewPaltz.com).
The origin (aka the actual web server) is currently just one instance of an Azure Web App. jewpaltzcom5783.azurewebsites.net

Everything works from a computer, or Android device. However, from an iPhone, I get either an error "oops! We weren't able to find your Azure Front Page service configuration" or `<h2>Our services aren't available right now</h2>`.

I've been able to replicate the issue sometimes in a 100% blank Android installation if I manually type in http://. But if you try a few times it goes through. And once it's gotten the https even once, it'll never go back to having a problem no matter what you try.

However iPhones continue to present a problem. No matter what settings I try in the AFD configuration, trying to access the website from an iPhone fails.

After a lot of playing around, I've gotten it to work so that all links that specifically include https:// work even on an iPhone, but people typing in our URL still won't redirect to https on iPhone.

Comment: Try checking the Front Door access logs to see if you can isolate the failing traffic.  You might try using a web browser to impersonate Safari traffic to see if you get the same error.  It may be something like the TLS version or just the web agent being sent across.

Comment: Yea, I have to figure out how to access the access logs and then how to filter them. Changing the agent doesn't do anything. I don't think it has to do with the agent, I think it has to do with how iPhone follows redirects. The biggest question is why isn't everyone seeing this issue